# Launch agents via ssh option is not available on 2.444.0

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, almalinux

I have upgraded jenkins from 2.426 to 2.444.0 with alma linux 9, not able to find launch agents via ssh option while launching nodes

SSH Build Agents plugin
Version2.877.v365f5eb_a_b_eec

SSH Agent Plugin
Version333.v878b_53c89511

launch agents via ssh option should be visible

Comment: provide logs from jenkins please